# Is there some problem with undoActions that prevents my two functions( redo and undo from working properly)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, gdi

So I've been trying to add a back and forward functions to my paint by numbers project, so that if the user accidently paints the wrong square the function back redraws the window to the state it was before the paint. And this function works fine, but my other function that does the opposite returns only the last undone square even if there were multiple undone squares in a row.
here are theese functions:

```
void UndoLastPaint(HWND hWnd)
{
    if (!paintedCoordinates.empty())
    {
        // Retrieve the coordinates of the last painted square
        int x = paintedCoordinates.back().first;
        int y = paintedCoordinates.back().second;

        // Check if the square was previously painted
        bool wasPainted = false;
        COLORREF color = RGB(255, 255, 255); // Default color if the square was not painted
        for (int i = paintedCoordinates.size() - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (paintedCoordinates[i].first == x && paintedCoordinates[i].second == y) {
                wasPainted = true;
                color = paintedColors[i]; // Store color from the loop
                // Store the undone action
                PaintAction undoneAction;
                undoneAction.x = x;
                undoneAction.y = y;
                undoneAction.color = color;
                undoneActions.push(undoneAction);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (wasPainted) {
            // Restore the previous color of the square
            RECT squareRect = { x * squareSize, y * squareSize, (x + 1) * squareSize, (y + 1) * squareSize };
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(color);
            FillRect(hdc, &squareRect, brush);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        }
        else {
            // Calculate the rectangle occupied by the last painted square
            RECT squareRect = { x * squareSize, y * squareSize, (x + 1) * squareSize, (y + 1) * squareSize };

            // Remove the last painted square from the screen
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, &squareRect, TRUE);
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);
        }

        // Remove the last painted square from the data collection
        paintedCoordinates.pop_back();
        paintedColors.pop_back();
    }
}


void MoveForward(HWND hWnd)
{
    if (!undoneActions.empty())
    {
        // Retrieve the coordinates and color of the last undone action
        int x = undoneActions.top().x;
        int y = undoneActions.top().y;
        COLORREF color = undoneActions.top().color;

        // Remove the next undone action from the stack
        undoneActions.pop();

        // Paint the square at the next undone action
        PaintSquare(hWnd, x, y);

        // Store the repainted square in the data collection
        paintedCoordinates.push_back({ x, y });
        paintedColors.push_back(color);
    }
}
```

that's why I think that stack undoneActions isn't functioning properly, but i can't figure out what is the exact problem

Comment: *that's why I think that stack undoneActions isn#t functioning properly* -- Assuming that `undoneActions` is a `std::stack`, there is nothing wrong with the functionality of `std::stack`.  What *may* be wrong is the logic you've written that uses it.

Comment: You say that the code you posted "works fine", but "my other function" doesn't work. Yet you never included the code for your "other function". Neither of these functions "returns" anything, so they aren't the troublesome function that "returns only the last undone square."

Comment: When you say "return", do you mean something along the lines of - return a square to its previous state (undo the changes), or do you mean the `return` statement (as in, for example, `int giveMeFive() { return 5; }`)?

Comment: i mean undo the changes

Comment: When you undo you're only removing the last element from the data collection, but you look back to find the previous one which might not be the last. You need to remove that previous one wherever it is in the history if you want to be able to go further back in time. There's also an error with your logic when looking back - size() is a size_t which is unsigned; if size() is 1, size() - 2 will underflow.